# SQL statement selecting a count of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(SDDOCO) AS Total 
FROM 
    KAIPRDDTA.F4211LA, KAIPRDDTA.Dates 
WHERE 
    SDDRQJ = Day10
```

which returns a count of all the orders for today.

I am trying to get a second column so that I have this:

[image: Sample]

To get orders that are not completed would be: SDNXTR < '562'. How would I add this to my sql query so that I can accomplish this goal? Let me know if you need anymore information and thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Tag which DBMS are you using

Comment: I am using SSMS

Comment: Yes, but I am using the query in a Web Form on Visual Studio 2012

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: That's a JDEdwards table.   Unless you've replicated it on SQL Server, you're using either DB2 (World) or Oracle (EnterpriseOne)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` statement to count that `SDNXTR < '562'`  values like below:

```
 SELECT count(SDDOCO) as Total, 
        sum(case when SDNXTR < '562' then 1 else 0 end) as not_yet_finished 
 FROM KAIPRDDTA.F4211LA, KAIPRDDTA.Dates
 WHERE SDDRQJ = Day10
```

Comment: This will not work. either change the else to `null`, or change the `count` to `sum`

Comment: Sorry again m sending through mobile that is y errors

Comment: This looks correct (although the formatting is painful) to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(SDDOCO) AS Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SDNXTR < '562' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Not_Finished_Yet_With_SUM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SDNXTR < '562' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Not_Finished_Yet_With_COUNT,
FROM 
    KAIPRDDTA.F4211LA, KAIPRDDTA.Dates 
WHERE 
    SDDRQJ = Day10
```

Comment: It didn't for me